# Where to store auth token to another system in ASP.NET application

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an ASP.NET Web Application that serves documents to the client. This document can be in a "separate" system. To get the document from that system I need to login, then it returns a token that I then use on every request I make to it. (the credentials for that system does not depend on the current user of my Application, I just have fixed username and password)

I would like to avoid logging in every time a document is requested, instead I would prefer to store the token (it expires after an hour) internally.

What is the recommended way to store this kind of variable?

Usage of static variable is discouraged and using `Session` would store the ticket only for a User.

Comment: Have an automatic process that runs every 55~59 minutes, logs in and saves the token to the database, and then have all your classes that use this system read that token from the database?

Comment: How about a cookie with 1hr expiry? Personally I dont store token in database unless I need to issue a refresh token. Other options include HTML5 web storages - Session storage (only available in the current tab, value gets cleared when tab is closed) and Local storage (value persists even after closing the tab/browser)

Comment: @Developer But this would store a different token for each different user(if I understand correctly) and I would like to avoid this

Comment: @MatteoUmili - yes, it does. I thought each user will have separate login credentials. I think what you have is app-app authentication, not user-app authentication. In that case, how about saving token in cache with 1hr expiry? try getting value from cache first, if its empty, then hit the auth service, get the token and save it to cache with expiry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you have is app-app authentication, not user-app authentication. In that case, how about saving token in cache with 1 hr expiry? 
So whenever the system tries to read the token, try getting value from cache first. If its empty - which means its first time login or expired cache - hit the auth service, get the token and save it to cache.

May be while in a load balanced environment, you might end up with each server having different tokens which I think is fine in your case. Or else you might need to consider something like Redis cache.

Answer (score 0):

As Josh recommended in comment above, storing token in the database would be better option.

How you refresh that token is a choice you need to make.

You can request a new token just before 5 minutes the old token expires by running a service or job. And your web application will just use the new token to retrieve the documents.

Also your web application can refresh the token. Whenever it uses the token from database, it can check for the expiry and if token is expiring in next 5 minutes the application can renew/refresh the token and store the new token with new expiry in the database and use it to retrieve the documents.

If storing in database is too complex then you can consider storing token and expiry on a temporary file on the web server itself and use any of the above two approach to refresh the token. The difference will be, the token is stored in a file instead of database.